# EF Core Transactions raw SQL memory use

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, transactions

I'm trying to understand how EF Core transaction with a lot of inner commands use memory.

Let's say I have code like this:

```
using var reader = new MyReader(myStream);
using var context = new BloggingContext();
using var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction();

try
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream()) 
    {
        var myObj = reader.ReadNextObject();
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([Col1], [Col2]) VALUES ({0}, {1})", 
                                       myObj.prop1, myObj.prop2);
    }

    transaction.Commit();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // Exception handling
}
```

`MyReader` is reading a very large (millions of rows) collection of records streamed from some source.

My questions are:

1. Can objects referenced by `myObj` variable be garbage collected before we commit the transaction, or are we effectively loading all of them into memory?
2. Are all SQL commands we set to execute stored in memory until we commit the transaction, or are they sent to the database immediately?
3. Am I understanding correctly, that this would lock `[MyTable]` until we commit the transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can objects references by myObj variable be garbage collected before we commit the transaction

Yes.  Once ExecuteSqlRaw completes, EF will not hold any references to the object that myObj refers to, and it can be collected.

> Are all SQL commands we set to execute stored in memory until we commit the transaction, or are they sent to the database immediately?

They are sent to the database immediately by `ExecuteSqlRaw`, the row is inserted and transaction log records written to the in-memory log buffer.  The transaction just prevents the statement from waiting until the log records are hardened to disk, and allows you to roll back the whole transaction.  And even the log records are not kept in memory on the server; they will be hardened to the log files asynchronously, and read back from there in the case of a rollback.

> Am I understanding correctly, that this would lock [MyTable] until we commit the transaction?

SQL Server will lock only the inserted rows, unless you inserted so many that it triggered lock escalation.

Comment: Thanks! I have a follow-up question, which is somewhat more opinion based so won't fit for its own Stackoverflow question. Let's say instead of just copying the rows from the stream directly I needed to do some more processing with them (e.g. break a row into multiple related tables), which approach would be preferable - the one outlined in my code above or using SQLBulkCopy to copy rows into a temp table and then calling a stored procedure to do the processing? I understand that the correct answer is "do benchmarks", but at even a very general advice would be appreciated!

Comment: SqlBulkCopy should be significantly better, as it doesn't run one statement-per-row.  Also in the "break a row into multiple related tables" scenario, building JSON docs and using OPENJSON on the server can be a good model.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "building JSON docs"?

Comment: Send a doc like `{"id":1214,"name":"foo", "details":[{"detailId":1,"description":"blah"}, {"detailId":2, "description":"blah2"}]"` to SQL Server as a string, and then using OPENJSON in TSQL to first scan and insert the root item, then scan and insert the two child rows.

Comment: And Lock escalation happens when more than **5000 rows** are inserted in a single transaction - so here that definitely would be the case

Comment: Sadly I have no control over the formatting of the files I get sent, so while OPENJSON seems actually really good to use, in this case it would require parsing the CSV file and converting it into the JSON format

Comment: @marc_s Should I separate the processing into multiple transactions to avoid lock escalation?

EDIT: I just realised that using SqlBulkCopy into new temporary table completely avoids lock escalation issues!